# Azure Active Directory B2B Alternate Login ID

Tags: azure, authentication, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

We want to use Azure AD as the Identity Provider for users in a web application. At the moment, we have everything set up using `MSAL.js 2.0` with the `Auth Code Flow`, a custom scope, and access token which is used to authenticate requests towards our various backend services.

The issue is that our users want to be able to login with their own custom email addresses, instead of their login ids generated by AD and with the `@onmicrosoft.com domain`. For example, `user1@some-orginization.com` or `user2@some-other-organization`.

It would still be okay to accept the login ids as usernames as well, but surely there must be a way to allow users to use another property of the profile (their alternate email for example) to log in.

Our application is registered to AD such that it will allow only logins from one tenant, since we don't want to require users to already have existing Microsoft Accounts.

We're avoiding B2C because some users would face issues with their company policies, which would mean they could be invited as users, but would be rejected at login. Also, B2C does not really support Roles like B2B does, which is somewhat important for us.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

After countless hours of attempting to make this work, I decided that it just isn't worth the effort, and switched to Auth0. They provide everything I could possibly want, and seemingly even better Azure AD integration to other tenants then Azure AD itself.

Comment: Are your users registered in Azure ad? I think a custom domain is definitely suitable for you.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain

Comment: @CarlZhao In that case I would have to register all kinds of domains, which I can't do. I want users to be able to log in using any email they want. It would be their own company issued email, but also gmail, yahoo, whatever. I don't see how custom domains can help me with that?

Comment: Then you only need to use the `/common` endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to express is that you want to log in to your application with any email (including personal accounts and social accounts).

If so, then you need to modify the application's **manifest** configuration and then change the `/tenant id` endpoint to the [`/common` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols#endpoints).

To change the setting for an existing AD App, navigate to the Manifest blade of it in the portal, find the [signInAudience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#signinaudience-attribute) attribute, set it with `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount` or `PersonalMicrosoftAccount`.

[image]

Comment: I want only registered users to be able to log in, as I need to be able to assign app roles to all users in AD. Will this be possible with such an approach?

Comment: @DinoPrašo  If the user is registered in AD, then the user will be uniformly assigned a default domain when registering, so this certainly cannot meet your requirements.

Comment: @DinoPrašo  However, for users who are not registered in AD, there are ways to meet your requirements. You can add personal accounts as guests to the tenant, so that you can assign application roles to users. When the user logs in, it can still log in with his original email.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal

Comment: I’ve tried invites, but I ran into issues where some users with custom company email addresses are denied on login. The message is something like “the domain owner has disabled self service account sign up via email validation” after I invite them and they try to log in.

Comment: @DinoPrašo  Users can be invited to the tenant, but cannot log in to the application, right?

Comment: @DinoPrašo  This may be a new problem.

Comment: Right. They can be invited, and for most domains it works fine (gmail, etc), but some domains have this issue. It seems to me like it would require changes on the users side to allow access, which is not particularly user friendly, especially since all my clients will actually be business customers, not random people online.

Comment: @DinoPrašo   What are your user settings?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsO5E.png,    https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbZVv.png

Comment: Guest user access is set to `Guest users have limited access to properties and memberships of directory objects` (option 2), the other two are both the first option (most inclusive)